# Wrong type in datetime column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, internationalization, date-formatting

I have an application in asp. I insert data into SQL Server into a column of `datetime` type.

Let me give you an example for my question:

when I have the date `10/02/2012` and I insert it into SQL Server I see the data like this:

```
 2012-10-02
```

but I would like to have it like this: `2012-02-10`

When I have the date `29/02/2012` and I insert it into SQL Server I see the data in the correct format :  `2012-02-29`.

How can I manage the correct type I want?

The collation of database and table is Greek_CI_AS , in my language

any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: What does the code look like that is doing the insert?  Also - to check if it is a display format issue you could do some DATEPART calls to see the day/month to see if it's being stored correctly.

Comment: I usually just use VBScript `FormateDateTime()` but it won't come out how you want it, just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities, but they all relate to the date format settings of the system components your strings are passing through (i.e. both the ASP runtime and your SQL Server).

There is a date format setting in SQL Server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx

In ASP, the parsing of strings in VBScript depends upon the settings in effect during the parse - basically, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306044

Comment: so u think i have to fix iis in server?

Comment: @perastikos1 You need to first understand when your dates are strings and where they are converted to and from datetime. When a form submits a datetime it is generally in text which is then parsed by VBScript according to regional settings if you are putting it into a variable. If your SQL is generated from VBScript then your datetime variables in VBScript are being converted to strings (again with session regional settings) and THEN being interpreted by the SQL parser depending upon the SQL Server settings. This last part does not apply with parameterized queries or stored procedures in ADO.

Comment: @perastikos1 Some dates are ambiguous: 10/02/2012 can be either 10-FEB-2012 or 02-OCT-2012. 02/29/2012 and 29/02/2012 are not ambiguous and unfortunately, they will always convert correctly in some parsers which are trying to be helpful.

Comment: @perastikos1 In all my internationalization work, I tend to make the settings explicit by forcing the thread locale in an appropriate part of the system - in ASP.NET we do it on each page.  Also it is important to choose the basis - whether it's user preference or database or whatever.  Sometimes that is difficult to decide, because an English user may be generating a report to send to Poland. ;-(

Comment: i understand what u mean and thanks for answer, before i insert the value in table i have a variable,i make visible this variable and its in correct type, so the problem is when i enter the variable in database, so whats your proposal? to change regional settings in server?

Comment: @perastikos1 How are you entering it into the database?  Ad hoc SQL like "INSERT INTO tbl (DateColumn) VALUES ('" & YourDateVariable & "')"?  This is vulnerable to ambiguity if you don't format explicitly.  I would use a canonical format or better yet, use a parametrized query and don't format the datetime at all.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx shows the date formats.

Comment: i use command rstTemp.Update to insert values on sql server from asp

Comment: @perastikos1 Post all your code then.  An updateable recordset should not go through a datetime-string conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CONVERT()` to control the date format and you can specify a smaller target string to crop the result:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 21) -- YYYY-MM-DD
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 102) -- YYYY.MM.DD
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105) -- DD-MM-YYYY
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) -- MM-DD-YYYY
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 105) -- DD-MM
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 110) -- MM-DD
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), GETDATE(), 102) -- YYYY

 -- To get YYYY-DD-MM, put two of the above together:
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), GETDATE(), 102)
       + '-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 105)
```

To force a date format for insertion, you can do a similar thing:

```
-- Insert in Italian dd-mm-yy (e.g. 10th February 2012)
INSERT INTO user_table VALUES (CONVERT(DATETIME, '10-02-12', 5));
-- Insert in USA mm-dd-yy (2nd October 2012)
INSERT INTO user_table VALUES (CONVERT(DATETIME, '10-02-12', 10));
```

See Microsoft MSDN reference [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

---- ANSWER TO ADDITIONAL QUESTION ----

I find your latest comment a little ambiguous. If you're asking how to search on a `datetime` field between two dates that you have in string format, then, try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   user_table
WHERE  mydate BETWEEN convert(Datetime,'20/02/2012',103)
              AND     convert(Datetime,'01/03/2012')
```

whereas, if you are trying to search on an `nvarchar` field with two dates in string format, then, try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   user_table
WHERE  convert(Datetime, mynvarchar, 103)
       BETWEEN convert(Datetime,'20/02/2012',103)
       AND     convert(Datetime,'01/03/2012')
```

However, this is terribly inefficient. If you are going to be doing date searches a lot, I highly recommend storing your date field in datetime format. If you have a business requirement to store the nvarchar version, that's okay, but you can use dynamic columns, such as:

```
CREATE TABLE user_table
(
     mynvarchar   NVARCHAR(10),      -- Date as a String in DD/MM/YYYY format
     mydatetime   AS CONVERT(DATETIME, mynvarchar, 103) PERSISTED
);
```

The advantage of this is the `mydatetime` field automatically updates itself and can be used in indexes and constraints if you wanted it to, but, you can manage it by manipulating the `mynvarchar` business columns.

In future, can I please request that when you ask question, that you provide more concrete examples, i.e. the name of your table, the name of your columns, so I don't have to keep inventing these.

Comment: thanks for answer, help me in something , i manage to insert varchar field with the format i want, for example 01/03/2012 is today, now i want to find rows between dates , for example i want to find rows between 20/02/2012 to 01/03/2012 but the problem is i cant compare varchar fields, how can i manage? if i try to convert varchar to datetime with this command : convert(Datetime,'01/03/2012',103) i take this result 03/01/2012 and i dont want that

Comment: Hi @perastikos1 I answered your question. I would appreciate an upvote. Your latest question, technically is a new question. In future, please provide more a concrete example to remove ambiguity and misinterpretation, i.e. name of your table and columns so I don't have to invent them.